# Programatically add Done button to Android MediaController subclass

Tags: android, button, mediacontroller

I want to add a Done button to a MediaController subclass. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    private class MediaControllerWithDoneButton extends MediaController {

        public MediaControllerWithDoneButton(android.content.Context context) {
            super(context);

            Button doneButton = new Button(this);
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error because there isn't a `Button` constructor that takes a `MediaController` instance as a parameter. Since I'm new to Android and Java I could use some help on how to proceed.

**More info:** error above is resolved. Now I'm wondering about the layout. Specifically how to make sure the Done button fits well with the default play/pause, rewind and fast-forward MediaController buttons.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `this` with `MyActivity.this` (Not literally "MyActivity", but whatever your activity's name is.  So in your case, `MediaControllerWithDoneButton.this`).

Comment: That helps, thanks. I think there's a typo in your answer though. You replaced the activity name with the MediaController subclass name. Like you mentioned it should be MyActivity or equivalent.